# Is it ok to fire database queries again and again?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am preparing a Java project and working on MySQL database.
Currently I am stuck at a point where I want size of the resultset before I can actually fetch entries from it.

The fetching of size is such that I will be requiring to fire 6-7 queries.
The button on which the above event will occur is pressed frequently. 
This is Okay to do this?

Would this slower down the functioning of the project?

Comment: Every query takes time to execute.  The real question is whether it takes too long.  Only you know the answer to that.

Comment: Are you sure you need the size first? Why? Are you storing the results in an array?

Comment: Also wondering why you need this and why it take 6-7 queries to get the row count?  Wouldn't count(*) suffice?

Comment: Queries are run again and again everywhere.

Comment: Yes because first i want to now how many unique items are there ! 
then i want to know how many rows correponding to each unique item are there
With these 2 sizes i will be creating a 2d array which ill be using further.

Answer (score -1):

Discuss with the people responsible how large a database your application should be able to handle gracefully, and on which hardware. Then your development code should have an option to fill the database with fake data to reach that size (there are websites for example that can generate random fake addresses for fake people for you). Then you can answer the question yourself.